# Как сделать 2 равные блоки как на скриншоте?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

///////////////////////////////////////

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrap{width:100%;display:flex;}
.one, .two{width:50%;height:fit-content;}
.one{background:#777;    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;}
.two{background:#999;    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><div class="one">Сколько стоит «слипер»?
Грузовик на базе Volvo VNL860, о котором шла речь в самом начале, обойдётся покупателю в 300 тысяч долларов. В среднем за тягач приходится выложить 120-150 тысяч долларов и ещё столько же за сам «слипер», но не стоит забывать, что комплектации у «дворцов на колёсах» разные и они влияют на финальную стоимость.</div><div class="two">Сколько стоит «слипер»?
Грузовик на базе Volvo VNL860, о котором шла речь в самом начале, обойдётся покупателю в 300 тысяч долларов. В среднем за тягач приходится выложить 120-150 тысяч долларов и ещё столько же за сам «слипер», но не стоит забывать, что комплектации у «дворцов на колёсах» разные и они влияют на финальную стоимость.</div></div>
```